# find locked table and unlock them in mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I am very newcomer to programming and Mysql,so this question might seem a little silly,I tried to check locked tables and unlock them by calling this scipt in my fallowing code :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   

    system("./Unlock");


...
}
```

and this is my script file(Unlock) content:

```
#!/bin/bash -e  
sudo mysql myDbName -u Myuser </..path/unLock.sql
```

and this is unlock.sql :

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
 quit
exit 0
```

but it does not work in my application , in other words this script does not unlock tables.
Is there any way to solve it or is there any other command for unlock tables?

Comment: No, this won't work, because table locks are held by individual connections, and only the connection that locked a table can unlock it... which happens implicitly if the connection holding the lock is killed... but a more important question than "why doesn't this work?" is "why are you trying to do this?"  It's [important](http://xyproblem.info) to ask about your actual problem, rather than asking about your attempted solution.

Comment: Table locks are specific to a session. So opening a new session (basically: a connection to your server) and executing `unlock tables` will not do anything (because this session had no locks yet). Only the session that locked your tables can unlock them (a lock is not very useful if anyone can unlock it). What problem are you trying to solve here? If you have table locks (by other sessions): you have to fix that in the scripts that aquired that locks - always unlock tables as soon as you don't need the lock anymore. Or, since its 2016: look into transactions/innodb.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, my real problem is some times my tables lock and i cant do any thing , for avoiding this situation i decided to unlock table at the start of my program

Comment: what you really ought to be doing is to look at your queries and finding why they are not releasing locks. Anyway what's the point of writing a one liner c program to execute a one liner shell script. Why not have system execute the mysql command direct (not that it's going to do you any good)

Comment: @Solarflare, as you gess my problem is beacause it is related to other session , so as you tell i cant unlock it ,and also i cant change my database structure (innodb/Transaction),so what do you think is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: @Ss.unix The only real solution is to unlock your tables in the script that locked it. It's like closing a file, releasing a mutex or freeing memory in c++: if you don't do it, other applications might be blocked if they need the same resource, and you would have to manually find and kill it (as an emergency solution, and you would not call your program fixed now). There's an equivalent in mysql: `show processlist`, identify the query that locked the tables, use `kill <id>` (it will kill the session). But it's not a fix, your scripts are still faulty. And may result in half executed scripts.

Comment: @Ss.unix And btw, innodb/transactions wouldn't solve the problem either (you would still have to commit a transaction too after you started it, and would run into similar problems if you wouldn't), they are just a (much) better version of table locks, so I wanted to at least mention them in case you are still in developing phase.